# How to access Session in hangfire (Authrize Method in IDashboardAuthorizationFilter's implementation) while using SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, hangfire

I am using hangfire and for authorization purposes, I am trying to access session value in Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)  method which is null. Please note that this problem has encountered after I have incorporated SignalR in my application.

If I remove the "app.MapSignalR();" line from startup.cs, I am able to access session successfully

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
...
app.MapSignalR(); //if I remove this line, session is accessible
...
}

public class MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter{

public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
{

 HttpSessionStateBase session = ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)(owinEnvironment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"])).Session; //Which is null

 session = HttpContext.Current.Session; //Also Null
 }
}
```

Please note that session value is null after I introduced " app.MapSignalR()" in Configuration method in startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

According to ASP.Net Core [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state), getting null value of session is normal behaviour.

*Session isn't supported in SignalR apps because a SignalR Hub may execute independent of an HTTP context. For example, this can occur when a long polling request is held open by a hub beyond the lifetime of the request's HTTP context.*

Also

*SignalR and session state
SignalR apps should not use session state to store information. SignalR apps can store per connection state in Context.Items in the hub.*

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#signalr-and-session-state)